# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException Error when running jar file, but run fine in IDE

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I just wrote a program in Eclipse (2022-03) as simple Java project (not even maven) that read excel on my computer into java (using Apache POI library) and write it to jasper report.
It run in Eclipse and report is generated perfectly fine. But when I export as runnable JAR and run it via command line, it got errors eventhough I include all the needed libraries in the JAR, include jasperreports-6.19.1.jar and poi-5.2.2.jar set.
I tried both jdk 1.8 and jdk 12.0.2, both fail.

run by command: java -jar .\jarname.jar

This is the error

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
D:\eclipse-workspace\Rent\Condo_1651557749766_654059.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
public class Condo_1651557749766_654059 extends JREvaluator
                                                ^
  symbol: class JREvaluator
D:\eclipse-workspace\Rent\Condo_1651557749766_654059.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    private JRFillParameter parameter_MONTH = null;
            ^
  symbol:   class JRFillParameter
  location: class Condo_1651557749766_654059
D:\eclipse-workspace\Rent\Condo_1651557749766_654059.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    private JRFillParameter parameter_YEAR = null;
            ^
  symbol:   class JRFillParameter
  location: class Condo_1651557749766_654059
D:\eclipse-workspace\Rent\Condo_1651557749766_654059.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    private JRFillField field_roomType = null;
            ^
  symbol:   class JRFillField
  location: class Condo_1651557749766_654059
D:\eclipse-workspace\Rent\Condo_1651557749766_654059.java:4: error: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
^
D:\eclipse-workspace\Rent\Condo_1651557749766_654059.java:5: error: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.*;
^
D:\eclipse-workspace\Rent\Condo_1651557749766_654059.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        parameter_MONTH = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("MONTH");
                           ^
  symbol:   class JRFillParameter
  location: class Condo_1651557749766_654059
D:\eclipse-workspace\Rent\Condo_1651557749766_654059.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        parameter_YEAR = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("YEAR");
                          ^
  symbol:   class JRFillParameter
  location: class Condo_1651557749766_654059
D:\eclipse-workspace\Rent\Condo_1651557749766_654059.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
        field_roomType = (JRFillField)fm.get("roomType");
                          ^
  symbol:   class JRFillField
  location: class Condo_1651557749766_654059
9 errors
.
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:229)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:358)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:344)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:609)
        at GenerateJasper.generateReport(GenerateJasper.java:40)
        at ExcelRead.main(ExcelRead.java:86)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
```

And this is part of my code that use jasper report library

```
try {
            JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);
 
 
            HashMap<String, Object> dataParam = new HashMap<>();
            dataParam.put("MONTH", date.substring(0, 2));
            dataParam.put("YEAR", date.substring(2, 6));
 
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/eclipse-workspace/Rent/jasper/Condo.jrxml"));
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, dataParam, jrDataSource);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputPath+"/"+outputName));
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: `I include all the needed libraries in the JAR` - Did you check that your jar file containes all libraries? What tool did you use for building fat jar (in case you really built fat jar)?

Comment: Try including an ECJ jar, for instance https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/ecj/3.21.0/jar

Comment: @AlexK Eclipse. Export > Runnable JAR file > Package required libraries into generated JAR. Yes, it's fat JAR (66MB. It's just for home use tho.) and I checked the libraries inside of it. It's looks fine.

Comment: @dada67
IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM! Thank you! So I need this ECJ jar everytime I make a runnable JAR from Eclipse?

Comment: With an ECJ jar report compilation would work seamlessly.  There are alternatives, but additional configuration is needed.

Answer (score 0):

After adding ECJ jar as library, the jar run just fine.